# RDS data model design for storing playlists and associated tracks?

Tags: sql, database-design, many-to-many, relational-database

What would be the optimal way to store and access playlist_id and track_id in a playlist table?
I am thinking of storing multiple track_ids in an array for a given playlist! what would be the pros and cons?

Comment: Arrays and the relational paradigm are a contradiction in itself. Either you are ready to store one row per track_id, or you go JSON , or another , more flexible, and less efficient, format ....

Comment: as the track increases the size of the table containing playlist_id and track_id one per row grows. Would it be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You have a many-to-many relationship between playlists and tracks, where each track may belong to multiple playlists, and a playlist contains multiple tracks.

In SQL, this is typically represented with a brigde table:

```
create table tracks (
    track_id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    ...
);

create table playlists (
    playlist_id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    ...
);

create table playlist_tracks (
    playlist_track_id int primary key,
    playlist_id int references playlists(playlist_id),
    track_id int references tracks(track_id),
    pos int,
    unique (playlist_id, pos)
);
```

The `playlist_tracks` table is the bridge table, that links the two referencial tables (`tracks` and `playlists`). I added another column, called `pos`, which references the position of each track in each playlist.

I would not recommend using arrays (or other structured datatype such as JSON) to store a playlist's track. You have a well-defined model, which, in a relational database, is best stored with separate table, as shown above.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed explanation! I have the tables for tracks and playlist, but now i need to setup a table for playlist store i,e playlist_tracks. If i have the playlist_tracks as defined above, the table grows quickly as the playlist/tracks in playlist increases! So, what would be an optimal way?